# how do I incorporate my node.js file into a postman request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman, amazon-cognito

I am currently trying to get a script that generates two tokens for aws cognito authentication, and use it in my postman tests. Here is the code I am trying to integrate...

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const CognitoSDK = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js-node');

var authenticationData = {
  Username: 'username', 
  Password: 'password' 
};
var authenticationDetails = new CognitoSDK.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
var poolData = {
  UserPoolId: 'aws_region',
  ClientId: 'aws_user_client_id'
};
var userPool = new CognitoSDK.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
var userData = {
  Username: 'username', 
  Pool: userPool
};
var cognitoUser = new CognitoSDK.CognitoUser(userData);
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
  onSuccess: function (result) {
      console.log('access token + ' + result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
      /*Use the idToken for Logins Map when Federating User Pools with Cognito Identity or when passing through an Authorization Header to an API Gateway Authorizer*/
      console.log('idtoken + ' + result.idToken.jwtToken);
  },
  onFailure: function (err) {
      console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
  },
});
```

I can run this file from the command line and it returns 2 tokens, but when I try to incorporate this into postman via copying and pasting the previous code into the pre-request script, or saving it as a global variable and using the eval function, I get the following error in Postman:

There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script:  Error: Cannot find module 'aws-sdk'

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Pre-request scripts are run before sending the request itself, nothing more. You are trying to import a package, but Postman has no clue as to what that is, there's no npm per se to import those external JS files. There is a workaround, place your external (*aws-sdk*) script as an enviroment variable and then run

```
eval(postman.getGlobalVariable('your_aws_sdk_code'))
```

AFAIK this is the simplest way, and it's synchronous (I believe it's more suitable in your case than other methods). Postman is still working on incorporating a simpler way, you can read more about it on their [github](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1180).

Comment: Topic revival. @Z.Baker
Short question.

I know how to set simple functions in pm global variables, then calling them from Test section using the eval trick.

However, I don't know how to import complex projects (like aws_sdk) in 1 simple global var.... Can you share your procedure ?

For me it should be as simple as copying the js code in the global var...

Many thanks in advance for any feedback.
Bregards,
MG.